# How use sql.js-httpvfs library in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I try to use **sql.js-httpvfs** library inside my project. However, I am not successed yet. I am not expert about node.js.

What I do?
Firstly, need to **webpack.config** to Gatsby for that I create **gatsby-node.js** file and add the below code inside it.

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: "/.tsx?$/",
          use: "ts-loader",
          exclude: "/node_modules/",
        },
      ],
    },
    output: {
      filename: "bundle.js",
    },
    devServer: {
      publicPath: "/dist",
    },
  });
};
```

Inside my index.js page, I add the code;

```
import { createDbWorker } from "sql.js-httpvfs";

const workerUrl = new URL(
  "sql.js-httpvfs/dist/sqlite.worker.js",
  import.meta.url
);

const wasmUrl = new URL("sql.js-httpvfs/dist/sql-wasm.wasm", import.meta.url);

function load() {
  const worker = createDbWorker(
    [
      {
        from: "inline",
        config: {
          serverMode: "full",
          url: "../myTestDb.sqlite3",
          requestChunkSize: 4096,
        },
      },
    ],
    workerUrl.toString(),
    wasmUrl.toString()
  );

  const result = worker.db.query(`select * from districts`);

  document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
}

load();
```

But I got error.
[image]

There is no any created bundle.js or folder like dist.

Comment: I'm not sure about your webpack configuration. Can you paste some references?

Comment: In Gatsby documantation, use gatsby-node.js for webpack configuration and it is included in question. Do I miss something?

Comment: I meant, where the `entry`, `module` and `output` references comes from?

Comment: I share my example repo. Of course it is not working... https://github.com/iozcelik/sqlite-test